PySpark JDBC to Microsoft Access: Error with Ucanaccess "incompatible data type"
I am using PySpark to connect to a Microsoft Access database using JDBC. Below is my code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("AccessToSpark") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "net.sf.ucanaccess:ucanaccess:5.0.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

connectionProperties = {
    "driver": "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"
}

url = f"jdbc:ucanaccess://{db_file_path}"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table="customers", properties=connectionProperties)

df.printSchema()
df.show()

When I run this code, df.printSchema() works fine and produces the following schema:
root
 |-- Customer ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- First Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Last Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Email Address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Phone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- State: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Zip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Notes: string (nullable = true)

However, when I call df.show(), I encounter the following error:
An error occurred while calling o37.showString. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (192.168.1.239 executor driver): net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 incompatible data type in conversion: from SQL type CHARACTER to java.lang.Integer, value: Customer ID at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getInt(UcanaccessResultSet.java:510)

Don't know if spaces are causing this issue but could at some point. I would always advise not to use spaces nor punctuation in object naming no matter what interface is used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053095/how-to-express-a-column-which-name-contains-spaces-in-spark-sql

Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813950/load-ms-access-table-as-dataframe-in-spark
